# sql query to find the second '/' in the column value and split into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can I know how can I  get only the data after the second '/'. It okay if they are broke into three columns but I have to use the data after the second delimiter.

Path:

/abc/US/123

/dd/IN/222

output:

US

IN

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option which uses a bit of XML.

To be clear, we use `....value('/x[3]'...` due to the leading `/`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,path varchar(100))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'/abc/US/123')
,(2,'/dd/IN/222')


Select ID
      ,SomeValue = Cast('<x>' + replace(path,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
ID  SomeValue
1   US
2   IN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot John!!

Comment: @Akhira Always happy to help